# Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}{a_n={1\over n^{k+1}}{(1^k+\cdots+n^k)}}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}{a_n={1\over n^{k+1}}{(1^k+\cdots+n^k)}}$. Given what I have learned, I should be using Riemann sums but I am having a problem arriving at one. What I did is the following: $a_n=\sum_{a=1}^{n}{1\over n}{({a\over n})^{k}}$. That is $\Delta x={1\over n}$ and ${({a\over n})^k}=f({a\over n})$. I am having trouble, however, turning it into an integral, which is why I could really use your help.

Comment: It is a Riemann sum of $x^k$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 x^kdx = \dfrac{1}{k+1}$. If you know some more analysis, you can do it by applying the Stolz theorem. Try it to see how it goes. To break it down the above integral: You set $f(x) = x^k, [a,b] = [0,1], \triangle x = \dfrac{b-a}{n} = \dfrac{1-0}{n} = \dfrac{1}{n}, x_i = i\triangle x = \dfrac{i}{n}, i = 1,2,\cdots, n\Rightarrow a_n = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\triangle x = \dfrac{1}{n^{k+1}}\left(1^k+2^k+\cdots + n^k\right)\Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 x^kdx = \dfrac{1}{k+1}$.

Comment: How did you deduce that? Getting there is where I need help.

Comment: Its a standard riemann sum. Check the edit !